# How to estimate betas with rolling period? Rolling applymap (pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

I would like to estimate betas (multivariate approach) with a rolling period (let's say 100). The formula works if I want to estimate betas for all my DataFrame, but unfortunalety I do not find how to do it with the `rolling`.

I believe I need to use the [rolling apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html)
method to make it work, but it seems the method makes calculations for each columns separately. If I want to make a multivariate approach, I must use all columns in my rolling. There is a "method" parameter in the rolling function but I am not sure how it works. I would also not have a for loop solution, it is important that it has to be quite fast.

Suppose we have the following information:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(100)
window=100

data = np.random.normal(size=(2000, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Y", "X1", "X2", "X3"])
X = df[["X1", "X2", "X3"]]
Y = df[["Y"]]
```

with the following formula to estimate beta:

```
beta = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(Y)
```

How can I have a DataFrame with the same size/shape as `X` and with rolling beta for the corresponding window?

Thank you!